# Sierra: can't change Magic Mouse scrolling speed

Tags: macos, mouse

Since one of the recent updates I no longer see the option to change the scrolling speed of my Magic Mouse. It's way too slow. Any way to speed it up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You control scrolling via: System Preferences>Accessibility>Mouse & Trackpad>Mouse Options>Scrolling>

You can vary the scroll speed and inertia.
[image]

Comment: Aha! Thanks @Gilby. (I should've just searched for "scroll" in sys prefs.)

Comment: Wow, why would they hide this option behind all those clicks? That should be in the Mouse preferences pane.